# Select salva mesmos dados em 2 campos distintos

Tags: php, sql, select

Preciso que quando o funcionário selecione o produto o *input* "código do produto" seja preenchido automaticamente, até aqui está tudo certo porém quando gravo os dados no BD, os campos **produto** e **codigo_produto** ficam com os mesmos dados(no caso o código do produto).

```
<select name="produto" id="produto">
<option value="" disable>Escolha um produto:</option>
<?php
require "conexao.php";
$sql = mysql_query("select * from produto");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
       print '<option value="'.$row['codigo_produto'].'">'.$row['nome'].'</option>';
    }
?>
</select><br/>
<input name="codigo_produto" id="codigo_produto"><br />
```

Código de gravação do Formulário:

```
$produto = $_POST["produto"]; 
$codigo_produto = $_POST["codigo_produto"]; 
$quantidade = $_POST["quantidade"]; 
$solicitante = $_POST["solicitante"]; 
$log = date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); 
$string_sql = "INSERT INTO op (codigo,produto,codigo_produto,quantidade,solicitante,log) VALUES (null,'$produto','$codigo_produto','$quantidade','$solicitante',NOW())";
```

Comment: Porque estás a utilizar o *codigo_produto* como value da option no select. E é esse value que é passado para o POST.

Comment: e não existe uma forma para que eu consiga gravar o nome em um campo e código em outro sem ter que usar 2 tabelas diferentes?

Comment: Mostre o código onde são gravadas as informações do form.

Comment: $produto = $_POST["produto"];
          $codigo_produto = $_POST["codigo_produto"];
     $quantidade = $_POST["quantidade"];
     $solicitante = $_POST["solicitante"];
     $log  = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
     
     
    $string_sql = "INSERT INTO op (codigo,produto,codigo_produto,quantidade,solicitante,log) VALUES (null,'$produto','$codigo_produto','$quantidade','$solicitante',NOW())";

Comment: Basta que no código onde gravas o form fazeres um `select nome from produto where codigo_produto=$_POST['produto']` e só depois gravares os 2 campos.

Comment: Isso ou crias um *input hidden*: `<input type=hidden name="produto" id="produto">` tens é de mudar o *name* e o *id* do *select*.

Comment: Como fica o código com o select antes do insert?

Comment: Vê a minha resposta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema é que ao ires buscar `$produto = $_POST["produto"];` isso vai te devolver o valor do item selecionado: `value="'.$row['codigo_produto'].'"`.

Podes Criar um campo *hidden* e passa-lo para depois gravar, mantendo a gravação intacta:

```
<select name="produtoSelect" id="produtoSelect">
<option value="" disable>Escolha um produto:</option>
<?php
require "conexao.php";
$sql = mysql_query("select * from produto");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
       print '<option value="'.$row['codigo_produto'].'">'.$row['nome'].'</option>';
    }
?>
</select><br/>
<input name="codigo_produto" id="codigo_produto"><br />
<input type=hidden name="produto" id="produto"><br />
```

**Ou** então pesquisar o nome do campo antes de gravar:

```
$produto = $_POST["produto"]; 
$codigo_produto = $_POST["codigo_produto"]; 
$quantidade = $_POST["quantidade"]; 
$solicitante = $_POST["solicitante"]; 
$log = date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); 

$search_sql=  mysql_query("select nome from produto where codigo_produto=$produto");

if ($row = mysql_fetch_array($search_sql)) 
     $produto_nome = $row['nome'];

$string_sql = "INSERT INTO op (codigo,produto,codigo_produto,quantidade,solicitante,log) 
VALUES(null,'$produto_nome','$codigo_produto','$quantidade','$solicitante',NOW())";
```

NOTA:

Só mais uma coisa usa [mysqli](https://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.mysqli.php) em vez de [mysql](https://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.mysql.php) que será descontinuada em breve!

Comment: SIM, funcionou, muito obrigado pelo apoio!

Comment: Sim pretendo aprender mysqli.